# How I can make select from database WHRE in Array

Tags: php, sql, tarantool

I need to make a database query that includes several `WHERE` conditions.

The problem is that I cannot correctly pass the **$messages** array into the request.

```
public function Controller(Request $request)
    {
        $firstDate = $request->input('start');
        $secondDate = $request->input('end');
        $messages = $request->input('messages');
        $data = $this->client->executeQuery( "SELECT sum('count') as 'var', 'firstname', 'surname' FROM 'table' WHERE 'surname' IN (?) AND 'time' BETWEEN ? AND ? group by 'surname' ORDER BY 'var' desc limit 10",
            [$messages, $startDate, $endDate]);
        $data = $data ->getData();

        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

But as a result, I get a mistake:

> message: "Bind value type ARRAY for parameter 1 is not supported"

I use `tarantool` database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your syntax is incorrect, it should be

```
executeQuery('...', $messages, $startDate, $endDate);
```

instead of

```
executeQuery('...', [$messages, $startDate, $endDate]);
```

(please note the redundant `[]` in your version).

Second, If I understand your question correctly, you need to unfold your `$messages` array and pass each value as a separate argument to `executeQuery()`. In addition, you need to dynamically construct your SQL statement with as many placeholders inside `IN()` as the `$message` array size. Something like this:

```php
$placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($messages)), ',');
$params = $messages;
$params[] = $startDate;
$params[] = $endDate;

$sql = "... IN ($placeholders) AND 'time' BETWEEN ? AND ? ...";
$result = $this->client->executeQuery($sql, ...$params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are unsupported in SQL now, so you can't bind values of array type (exactly what error message says). You can track progress of supporting this feature by subscribing to corresponding issue: https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/issues/4762

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep an eye on it!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$messages = $request->input('messages');
$messages = implode(',',$messages);
```

then your code

Comment: Before writing here, I tried a lot of things. Including this one. The result is the same. Thank you!